# setting the default button in preinitialization

Tags: apache-flex, defaultbutton

I have a more than one container in a view. I am trying to set default button at the moment page is loaded so that when I press enter, function that handles keydown event called. If I simply set default button in preinit() function, it does not work.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to debug "Does not work" sometimes.  But, in this case I suspect you get a "Null value" style error.

The preinitialize event is fired before createChildren() so most likely the button you want make the "Default" doesn't exist yet.  More info about the [Flex Component LifeCycle](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html).

You can move your code to the initialize event.

I assume that by "setting the default" you mean you are using the [FocusManager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/FocusManager.html) to give your button focus?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, you need to do **two** things to make this work.

1. Set the defaultButton
2. Set focus to the container or some child of the container

As @Flextras said, preinit may also not be the best choice for this.

If the container is declared in MXML, I recommend setting the defaultButton property in the MXML declaration, and setting focus on creationComplete.